# Need help understanding if a function is increasing or decreasing

Tags: derivatives, logarithms, gamma-function

I am working on understanding the following function:

$$g(x) = \ln\Gamma\left(\frac{x}{4}\right) - \ln\Gamma\left(\frac{x}{5}+\frac{1}{2}\right) - \ln\Gamma\left(\frac{x}{20}+\frac{1}{2}\right) - 2(1.03883)\left(\sqrt{\frac{x}{4}}\right) - (1.03883)\left(\frac{x}{8}\right) +  \ln\Gamma \left(\frac{x}{10}\right) - \ln\Gamma\left(\frac{x}{12}+\frac{1}{2}\right) - \ln\Gamma \left(\frac{x}{60}+\frac{1}{2}\right)$$

Using [this series](http://dlmf.nist.gov/5.7#E6) for the digamma, I am using:

$$\frac{d}{dx}(\ln\Gamma(x)) = \psi(x) = -\gamma + \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{k+1} - \frac{1}{k+x}\right) $$

So that:

$$g'(x) = 2\gamma + \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(\frac{-2}{k+1} + \frac{1}{k+\frac{x}{5}+\frac{1}{2}} + \frac{1}{k + \frac{x}{20} + \frac{1}{2}} - \frac{1}{k+\frac{x}{4}} + \frac{1}{k+\frac{x}{12} + \frac{1}{2}} + \frac{1}{k + \frac{x}{60} + \frac{1}{2}} - \frac{1}{k+\frac{x}{10}}) - \frac{0.519415}{\sqrt{x}} -0.12985375$$

On the surface, I can't see how I would prove this is increasing for $x \ge 214$?  Did I make a mistake in the derivative?  Is there some trick to show that this function increases for $x \ge 214$?

Yet, when I look at Wolfram Alpha at $214 \le x \le 1000$, the [graph](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+ln+%28Gamma%28+x%2F4%29+%29-+ln+%28Gamma%28+x%2F5%2B+1%2F2%29+%29+-+ln+%28Gamma%28+x%2F20%2B+1%2F2%29%29+-+2%281.03883%29+sqrt%28x%2F4%29+-+%281.03883%29%28+x%2F8%29+%2B+ln+%28Gamma%28+x%2F10%29%29+-+ln%28+Gamma%28+x%2F12%2B+1%2F2%29%29+-+ln+%28Gamma%28+x%2F60%2B+1%2F2%29%29+for+x%3D214..1000), the function is increasing.

Does it continue to increase for $x > 1000$?

One thought that occurs to me is that I can analyze the following function:

$$h(k) = \frac{-2}{k+1} + \frac{1}{k+\frac{x}{5}+\frac{1}{2}} + \frac{1}{k + \frac{x}{20} + \frac{1}{2}} - \frac{1}{k+\frac{x}{4}} + \frac{1}{k+\frac{x}{12} + \frac{1}{2}} + \frac{1}{k + \frac{x}{60} + \frac{1}{2}} - \frac{1}{k+\frac{x}{10}}$$

I will see if I can prove that at a certain point, the sum is increasing.  If I make progress with this approach, I will post my thinking as an answer.

Thanks very much,

-Larry

---

**Edit:** I added a link to the graph based on a comment. The function starts increasing before $x$ gets to $214$.

Comment: Looks like it is actually decreasing: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+ln+%28Gamma%28+x%2F4%29+%29-+ln+%28Gamma%28+x%2F5%2B+1%2F2%29+%29+-+ln+%28Gamma%28+x%2F20%2B+1%2F2%29%29+-+2%281.03883%29+sqrt%28x%2F4%29+-+%281.03883%29%28+x%2F8%29+%2B+ln+%28Gamma%28+x%2F10%29%29+-+ln%28+Gamma%28+x%2F12%2B+1%2F2%29%29+-+ln+%28Gamma%28+x%2F60%2B+1%2F2%29%29+for+x%3D0..10

Comment: Hi @Samuel, I'm looking at the same graph for $x\le1000$ and [it](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+ln+%28Gamma%28+x%2F4%29+%29-+ln+%28Gamma%28+x%2F5%2B+1%2F2%29+%29+-+ln+%28Gamma%28+x%2F20%2B+1%2F2%29%29+-+2%281.03883%29+sqrt%28x%2F4%29+-+%281.03883%29%28+x%2F8%29+%2B+ln+%28Gamma%28+x%2F10%29%29+-+ln%28+Gamma%28+x%2F12%2B+1%2F2%29%29+-+ln+%28Gamma%28+x%2F60%2B+1%2F2%29%29+for+x%3D0..1000) looks like it is increasing to me.  Please let me know if I am misunderstanding.

Comment: Your pictures in fact correspond : it appears decreasing in (approximatively ) $[0,213.9)$ and increasing after that (around $213.89958216095$ to be more precise).

Comment: Thanks, Raymond.  So, my plan of attack should be to see what happens when $x$ gets to $214$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's evaluate the asymptotic expansion of the derivative.

We may use the well known [asymptotic expansion for $\psi$](http://dlmf.nist.gov/5.11) (with the error bounded by the first neglected term) :
$$\psi(x)\sim \ln(x)-\frac 1{2\,x}-\frac 1{12\,x^2}$$
 to get :
$$\frac {\psi\left(\frac x4\right)}4 - \frac {\psi\left(\frac x5 + \frac 12\right)}5 - \frac {\psi\left(\frac x{20} + \frac 12\right)}{20}\sim -\frac {\ln(4)}4 + \frac{\ln(5)}5 +\frac {\ln(20)}{20}-\frac 1{2\,x}-\frac {11}{8\,x^2}$$
and
$$\frac {\psi\left(\frac x{10}\right)}{10} - \frac {\psi\left(\frac x{12} + \frac 12\right)}{12} - \frac {\psi\left(\frac x{60} + \frac 12\right)}{60}\sim -\frac {\ln(10)}{10} +\frac {\ln(12)}{12} + \frac {\ln(60)}{60}-\frac 1{2\,x}-\frac {23}{6\,x^2}$$
while (your $\dfrac{0.519415}{x^2}$ in the derivative should be $\dfrac{0.519415}{\sqrt{x}}$) :
$$\left(- 2\cdot 1.03883\,\sqrt{\frac{x}{4}} - 1.03883\frac{x}{8}\right)'=-{1.03883}\left(\frac 1{2\sqrt{x}}+\frac 18\right)$$
Adding these three terms we get the asymptotic expansion of $g'(x)$ :
$$g'(x)\sim C-\frac{1.03883}{2\sqrt{x}}-\frac 1x-\frac {125}{24\,x^2}$$ 
with 
\begin{align}
C&=-\frac {\ln(4)}4 + \frac{\ln(5)}5 +\frac {\ln(20)}{20}-\frac {\ln(10)}{10} +\frac {\ln(12)}{12} + \frac {\ln(60)}{60}-\frac{1.03883}8\\
&=-\frac {3\ln(2)}{10}+\frac {\ln(3)}{10}+\frac{\ln(5)}6-\frac{1.03883}8\\
&\approx 0.040303
\end{align}

Now, setting $\,\displaystyle z:=\frac 1{\sqrt{x}}\,$, you may solve $\displaystyle C-\frac{1.03883}2z-z^2=0$ and get $\,x\approx 212.8\ $

Or better observe that for $\,x>214\,$ we get $\ \displaystyle C-\frac{1.03883}{2\sqrt{x}}-\frac 1x>\frac{125}{24\,x^2}\ $ and remember that the error in the asymptotic expansion of $\psi$ is bounded by the first neglected term so that $\ g'(x)>0$ for $x>214\ $ as wished !